# How do I find what data is involved memory leak?

Tags: c++, variables, memory-leaks

I have a program in C++, which fills my cube (database) with data, but the server in C++ has some memory leak, which is 34.9GB from 37.5GB. I don't have the source code of the server. Is there a way to find out where the memory leak happens or what data is involved in the memory leak?

**I am trying to use valgrind, but it's so slow that I estimate the time needed just to run that program on about 1 year, so that's not a way to go.**

Comment: You need debug symbols and if you do not have a debug version of the server application, it is going to be hard to find where the memory leak is located.

Comment: You could try doing a minimal run (with much, much less data) and see if valgrind turns up any useful information then. It should certainly run faster.

Comment: Can you change the parameters to fill a smaller cube?  The memory leak should still be there, but it will run fast enough to run through valgrind.

Comment: I am trying to run it only on 1152 values from 1152x576x40 as before, but only the start of the server takes with valgrind 20 minutes instead of some seconds normally. Maybe I will have a debug version on Monday.

Comment: You can already get partial results with valgrinds massif tool

Comment: So Valgrind tends to run 30x - 100x slower than your compiled app. How long does the process usually take? Are you sure your 1 year estimate is not actually a few hours? Try running it and going to lunch :).

Comment: OK, you are right, I try it. But the start of the server was more than 100 times slower, it was about 200x slower and the shutting down will be even more slow, because it takes longer normally. I will try it, but more than 8 hours is too much, because I will not run it from home, only at work.

Comment: OK, so only the start of the server took so long, the adding of values and shutting down was quick. But there is a fail, it measures the memory leaks at the end of the program, but I know it's OK at the end, but I need the memory leaks during the program or just get the values of memory leaks before the end of the program...

Comment: If memory is being properly cleaned up, then it is not leaking.  If some piece of your application still knows about the memory and _can_ clean it up, then by definition this is not a leak, but a performance/resource issue, which can be just as difficult to track down.

Comment: @Chad: judging by what OP said, I think the program exits in a way without cleaning up memory—so it may be impossible to tell what's actually leaked and what's simply in use at the time of exit.